# Get Attribute of XML Node String in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a PowerShell object which contains a property containing an XML String but not an entire XML Document - just the node. List this

```
$field.schemaxml;
<Field Type="Lookup" DisplayName="My Lookup" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" List="{447f56b0-0e38-461c-a0d2
-aa58e30ff270}" WebId="d31c0006-5576-4d1f-a0bb-ba3ce4ff787b" ShowField="Title" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE"
Group="_My Columns" ID="{dc1ee48c-7bf8-487d-b63f-bfda9aedec4c}" SourceID="{d31c0006-5576-4d1f-a0bb-ba3ce4ff787b}" Static
Name="My_x0020_Lookup" Name="My_x0020_Lookup" Version="1" />
```

What is the proper way using Powershell to parse this into an XML Node object, select the "List" attribute value (or any attribute for that matter) with xpath or some similar approach and change it.

Comment: What type is $field.schemaxml? You can determine it using `$field.schemaxml.GetType()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Attribute in your example is "StaticName" without a space, the following worked for me.

**PowerShell**

```
$node = '<Field Type="Lookup" DisplayName="My Lookup" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" List="{447f56b0-0e38-461c-a0d2
-aa58e30ff270}" WebId="d31c0006-5576-4d1f-a0bb-ba3ce4ff787b" ShowField="Title" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE"
Group="_My Columns" ID="{dc1ee48c-7bf8-487d-b63f-bfda9aedec4c}" SourceID="{d31c0006-5576-4d1f-a0bb-ba3ce4ff787b}" StaticName="My_x0020_Lookup" Name="My_x0020_Lookup" Version="1" />'

$xml = [xml]$node

Write-Output "Field is:"
Write-Output $xml.Field

Write-Output "Changing DisplayName...$([Environment]::Newline)"
$xml.Field.DisplayName = "New DisplayName"

Write-Output "Field is now:"
Write-Output $xml.Field
```

**Which give the following output:**

```
Field is:


Type                             : Lookup
DisplayName                      : My Lookup
Required                         : FALSE
EnforceUniqueValues              : FALSE
List                             : {447f56b0-0e38-461c-a0d2 -aa58e30ff270}
WebId                            : d31c0006-5576-4d1f-a0bb-ba3ce4ff787b
ShowField                        : Title
UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary : FALSE
Group                            : _My Columns
ID                               : {dc1ee48c-7bf8-487d-b63f-bfda9aedec4c}
SourceID                         : {d31c0006-5576-4d1f-a0bb-ba3ce4ff787b}
StaticName                       : My_x0020_Lookup
Name                             : My_x0020_Lookup
Version                          : 1

Changing DisplayName...

Field is now:
Type                             : Lookup
DisplayName                      : New DisplayName
Required                         : FALSE
EnforceUniqueValues              : FALSE
List                             : {447f56b0-0e38-461c-a0d2 -aa58e30ff270}
WebId                            : d31c0006-5576-4d1f-a0bb-ba3ce4ff787b
ShowField                        : Title
UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary : FALSE
Group                            : _My Columns
ID                               : {dc1ee48c-7bf8-487d-b63f-bfda9aedec4c}
SourceID                         : {d31c0006-5576-4d1f-a0bb-ba3ce4ff787b}
StaticName                       : My_x0020_Lookup
Name                             : My_x0020_Lookup
Version                          : 1
```