# Access fields in Powershell string containing XML

Tags: xml, powershell

How can I access the value of 'b' in the following string?

```
$x='<xml><obj a="Some" b="values" c="here"/></xml>'
```

According to [Get Attribute of XML Node String in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35930107/get-attribute-of-xml-node-string-in-powershell) I could access the field with

```
$y=[xml]$x
$y.obj.b
```

But there is no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You skipped the document element.

```
$y.xml.obj.b
```

will print `"values"`.